# Multiple consecutive newlines in JSON text translates to question mark using JSON_VALUE

Tags: json, sql-server

I have some JSON documents in a table where some of the fields have copy/paste text from Word documents with tabs and newlines. One example had 4 newlines in a row and I can't figure out why SQL is translating the way it does or what I should do about it.

Here's a quick sample:

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(50) = '{"text": "\n​\n\n\nStart"}'

SELECT JSON_VALUE(@json,'$.text')

SELECT STRING_ESCAPE(JSON_VALUE(@json,'$.text'),'json')
```

The first select returns  `?   Start` and the second returns `\n?\n\n\nStart`.

My plan was to use `STRING_ESCAPE` and then do a replace on the "\n" but that question mark is throwing things off. Any idea why that is happening and if I can stop it from translating that way?

Answer (score 0):

Between the first and second "\n" in your text, there is a UTF8 character `#e2808b`.  Copy and paste and feed to a hex editor:

```sh
$ echo '{"text": "\n​\n\n\nStart"}' |od -tc -tx1
```

returns

```
0000000   {   "   t   e   x   t   "   :       "   \   n 342 200 213   \
         7b  22  74  65  78  74  22  3a  20  22  5c  6e  e2  80  8b  5c
0000020   n   \   n   \   n   S   t   a   r   t   "   }  \n
         6e  5c  6e  5c  6e  53  74  61  72  74  22  7d  0a
0000035
```

SQL Server is displaying that as a `?`

Looks like it's a ["zero width space"](http://www.ltg.ed.ac.uk/%7Erichard/utf-8.cgi?input=e2+80+8b&mode=bytes)

SQL Server is not generating that character -- somehow that zero width space crept into your data.  Not uncommon when copying and pasting from Word docs.  And apparently, SQL Server does some sort of translation to an actual ASCII `?` character.  Here's an interesting illustration:

```sql
--                              123456789 123
declare @copied nvarchar(20) = '\n​\n\n\nStart'  -- copied from the SO question
       ,@typed  nvarchar(20) = '\n\n\n\nStart'  -- manually typed in
       ,@test   nvarchar(20) = '\n?\n\n\nStart' -- manually typed with "?" character
;
select len(@copied), len(@typed), case when @copied = @test then 'Equal' else '' end;

print cast(@copied as varbinary(40));
print cast(@typed  as varbinary(40));
print cast(@test   as varbinary(40));
print '';


with p02 as (select t.v from (values (1),(1),(1),(1)) t(v))
    ,p04 as (select t.v from p02, p02 t)
    ,num as (select v = row_number() over (order by (select null)) from p04)
select CharNum  = num.v
      ,CharVal  = chr.v
      ,ASCIIVal = ascii(chr.v)
from num
     cross apply (values (substring(@copied,num.v,1))) chr(v)
where num.v <= len(@copied)
order by num.v
;


                        
----------- ----------- -----
         14          13 Equal

(1 row affected)

0x5C006E003F005C006E005C006E005C006E0053007400610072007400
0x5C006E00    5C006E005C006E005C006E0053007400610072007400  -- manually added space for alignment
0x5C006E003F005C006E005C006E005C006E0053007400610072007400
 
             CharNum CharVal    ASCIIVal
-------------------- ------- -----------
                   1 \                92
                   2 n               110
                   3 ?                63
                   4 \                92
                   5 n               110
                   6 \                92
                   7 n               110
                   8 \                92
                   9 n               110
                  10 S                83
                  11 t               116
                  12 a                97
                  13 r               114
                  14 t               116

(14 rows affected)
```

Comment: But I don't understand why/how SQL is inserting/translating the simple text "\n\n\n\n" that way and how to stop it.

Comment: @pretzelb: see updated answer. The simple text "\n\n\n\n" isn't as simple as it appears.